# Showing PostGIS geography with OpenJUMP

Tags: pgadmin-3, openjump

I am trying to add data into open jump from a table in pgadmin. However there no geometry column in the table . I do have geography column. Can I transfer the geography to geometry ( i believe it ST_Transfer() method ) . Then add to open jump.

Additional information. There are other table within the database but they already have geom column.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get geography into your OpenJUMP map by using the Run Datastore Query tool. Normal way to add datastore layers does not work because in that case OpenJUMP is reading the metadata from the geometry_columns table from the database. If you have a table with geography those metadata are naturally missing.

But no worry, the Run Datastore Query tool is very flexible.

First create a table for testing and insert some data

```
create table geogtest (geog geography, id integer)
INSERT INTO geogtest (geog, id) VALUES (ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-110 30)'),1 );
```

Next write a query that is casting geography into geometry and run it with OpenJUMP

[image]

Check the result

[image]

This way you can select and view geography data in OpenJUMP but you can't edit geography tables.